# How to configure the web page of a web application to be browsed maximized?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, windows-server-2003, machine.config

I have developed a web project using PowerBuilder V12.0 and it is published in ASP.net web file formats (*.aspx).

I have hosted my web project on a web server machine with operating system (Windows Server 2003 - Enterprise Edition) and IIS V6.0 as Web Server Hosting Application.

I would like to make the home page (Default.aspx) opened maximized so that no internet toolbars appears in the Internet Explorere or any other internet browser like Firefox and so on.

It seems this is a web server configuration and setting as now I host the same web application in two development web servers and it opens maximized in one of them and opens normal in the other so No changes are needed in the web project files.

I do not know exactly what is this option or configuration,, Is there a property like window size or width and height in web configuration files like web.config and machine.config ? I guess there is a property like WindowSize:Maximized.

If you had experience with that before please let me know the options and configurations needed to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user - its not a server configuration. It depends on the clients browser preferences for each machine on which your application is opened within the browser. What you are trying to achieve is controlling the clients browser - which would be very annoying, even if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to resize the browser window but I think it's generally bad form and not always supported. Some browsers won't do it at all, some will block it, etc.

Pretty sure you can't control any other aspects of window display, such as toolbar visibility, etc. Well - you can when opening new browser windows but you can't enforce this on the first load of the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

Tried it in Chrome, no worky, tried it in IE, you get "IE has restricted this webpage from running scripts..."

I can see why you would want to enforce how your web app is displayed but that's something that's really left to the client.